R - multcompLetters Error undefined columns selected
I have a problem with the multcompLetters4 function. I have done anova and tukey test and now I want to generate letters for a boxplot with the function. I have seen a youtube video and did it exactly as in the video, but I get an error that I don't understand.
in my opinion there is no problem, but the error still occurs. i hope someone of you can help me.
Thanks!
This is my code:
SAD_data_Spur_mai_2019 <- SAD_data %>%
filter(Saison == 2019, Monat == 5, Art == "S. purpurea")
anova <- aov(Geh DT SAD (mg/g) ~ Individuum, data = SAD_data_Spur_mai_2019)
summary(anova)
tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)
print(tukey)
cld <- multcompLetters4(anova, tukey)
print(cld)
When i run it I get the following error:
Error in [.data.frame(data, , fm[[1]]) :
undefined columns selected
The result of the anova and tukey test is as follows:
summary(anova)
Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Individuum 7 32006 4572 20.88 6.33e-07 ***
Residuals 16 3503 219
Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)
print(tukey)
Tukey multiple comparisons of means
95% family-wise confidence level
Fit: aov(formula = Geh DT SAD (mg/g) ~ Individuum, data = SAD_data_Spur_mai_2019)
$Individuum
diff lwr upr
14_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT -26.739473 -68.567057 15.0881111
15_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 26.327669 -15.499915 68.1552532
46_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT -41.324086 -83.151670 0.5034978
47_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 23.937801 -17.889782 65.7653854
48_Spur_m_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 56.764234 14.936650 98.5918175
49_Spur_m_BT-01_Spur_m_BT -52.430203 -94.257787 -10.6026190
50_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT -36.311685 -78.139269 5.5158991
15_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 53.067142 11.239558 94.8947260
46_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT -14.584613 -56.412197 27.2429707
47_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 50.677274 8.849690 92.5048582
48_Spur_m_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 83.503706 41.676122 125.3312904
49_Spur_m_BT-14_Spur_f_BT -25.690730 -67.518314 16.1368538
50_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT -9.572212 -51.399796 32.2553719
46_Spur_f_BT-15_Spur_f_BT -67.651755 -109.479339 -25.8241714
47_Spur_f_BT-15_Spur_f_BT -2.389868 -44.217452 39.4377162
48_Spur_m_BT-15_Spur_f_BT 30.436564 -11.391020 72.2641483
49_Spur_m_BT-15_Spur_f_BT -78.757872 -120.585456 -36.9302882
50_Spur_f_BT-15_Spur_f_BT -62.639354 -104.466938 -20.8117702
47_Spur_f_BT-46_Spur_f_BT 65.261888 23.434304 107.0894715
48_Spur_m_BT-46_Spur_f_BT 98.088320 56.260736 139.9159036
49_Spur_m_BT-46_Spur_f_BT -11.106117 -52.933701 30.7214671
50_Spur_f_BT-46_Spur_f_BT 5.012401 -36.815183 46.8399852
48_Spur_m_BT-47_Spur_f_BT 32.826432 -9.001152 74.6540161
49_Spur_m_BT-47_Spur_f_BT -76.368004 -118.195588 -34.5404205
50_Spur_f_BT-47_Spur_f_BT -60.249486 -102.077070 -18.4219024
49_Spur_m_BT-48_Spur_m_BT -109.194437 -151.022020 -67.3668526
50_Spur_f_BT-48_Spur_m_BT -93.075918 -134.903502 -51.2483345
50_Spur_f_BT-49_Spur_m_BT 16.118518 -25.709066 57.9461020
p adj
14_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 0.3933857
15_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 0.4111698
46_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 0.0540480
47_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 0.5215084
48_Spur_m_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 0.0045869
49_Spur_m_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 0.0092309
50_Spur_f_BT-01_Spur_m_BT 0.1145835
15_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 0.0083286
46_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 0.9182967
47_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 0.0122493
48_Spur_m_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 0.0000758
49_Spur_m_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 0.4394725
50_Spur_f_BT-14_Spur_f_BT 0.9911607
46_Spur_f_BT-15_Spur_f_BT 0.0008144
47_Spur_f_BT-15_Spur_f_BT 0.9999990
48_Spur_m_BT-15_Spur_f_BT 0.2547920
49_Spur_m_BT-15_Spur_f_BT 0.0001511
50_Spur_f_BT-15_Spur_f_BT 0.0017916
47_Spur_f_BT-46_Spur_f_BT 0.0011838
48_Spur_m_BT-46_Spur_f_BT 0.0000102
49_Spur_m_BT-46_Spur_f_BT 0.9795015
50_Spur_f_BT-46_Spur_f_BT 0.9998513
48_Spur_m_BT-47_Spur_f_BT 0.1866024
49_Spur_m_BT-47_Spur_f_BT 0.0002154
50_Spur_f_BT-47_Spur_f_BT 0.0026218
49_Spur_m_BT-48_Spur_m_BT 0.0000025
50_Spur_f_BT-48_Spur_m_BT 0.0000200
50_Spur_f_BT-49_Spur_m_BT 0.8727430
i also tried to convert it into a dataframe, but i get the same error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
